# Stopping thread in UnhandledExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a Winforms application which has a Winform control and starts a thread.
To capture the exceptions which the Winform control raises, I implement the ThreadExceptionHandler.
When an exception in the control occurs, I want to do two things: log it and stop the thread so that the application can stop. The problem is that I don't have access to the logger and to the thread in the ThreadExceptionhandler, because it is static. Hence, I'm not able to perform the logging and worse, end the thread.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        MainForm form = null;
        try
        {

            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MainForm.ThreadExceptionHandler);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            form = new MainForm();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            form.logger.log(ex);
            form.thread.Stop();
        }
    }
```

and the MainForm class:

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
    internal MyThread thread;
    internal Logger logger = new Logger();
    public MainForm()
    {
        MyForm formThatThrowsAnException = new MyForm();
        thread = new MyThread();
        thread.Isbackground = false; // prevents app from stopping
    }

    internal static void ThreadExceptionHandler(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            // log here
            // stop thread here
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

}

I tried to make it this way:

```
        MainForm form = null;
        try
        {
            form = new MainForm();
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(form.ThreadExceptionHandler);
           ...
```

and remove the static keyword from the exception handler method but that didn't work because the method didn't get invoked.

Comment: The simplest way is to declare a static variable of type `MainForm` and assign the value of `form` to that before `Application.Run()`. Then you can access that static variable from the exception handler.

Comment: First, if you've trapped an exception here, the thread that threw the exception is already dead. As far as accessing the logger, you could make the logger `static`. There are multiple ways you could expose the logger to the exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

**MyThread**

```
internal static void Stop(){...}
```

**Logger**

```
internal static void log(){...}
```

**Main form:**

```
internal MyThread thread;
internal Logger logger = new Logger();

public MainForm()
{
    MyForm formThatThrowsAnException = new MyForm();
    thread = new MyThread();
    thread.Isbackground = false; // prevents app from stopping

}

internal static void ThreadExceptionHandler
              (object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs args){
    try
    {
          Logger.log(new Exception());
          MyThread.Stop();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

**Main function:**

```
static void Main()
{
    MainForm form = null;
    try
    {
        Application.ThreadException += MainForm.ThreadExceptionHandler;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form = new MainForm();
        Application.Run(form);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (form != null)
        {
            Logger.log(ex);
            MyThread.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but Logger is not a function, it's an object in the MainForm class. I need this object also there because I want to log stuff there too. In addition, how should I end the thread?

Comment: This was an example as I dont know what your logger class does. But you should get the point. As for the thread you have to understand ThreadException is not about what u think. Its the main thread in winform that throw exception

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how an UnhandledExceptionHandler should help me. How should I access an instance member (logger) in a static ExceptionHandler? Have a look at my MainForm class where I create the logger. I've told already that "MyForm" object throws an exception. As I said, the ThreadExceptionHandler gets called and the result is that the "MyThread" object doesn't get killed. Maybe you could show me how you would end the thread and access the logger object in your handlers